# How to initialize Spring container through apache tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

Other than through servlet do we have any other way's to initializes Spring container in Apache tomcat.

Thx,
Prikshit

Comment: Please add some context, what do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Just try your favorite search engine for a spring tutorial.
There are plenty and I'm sure most of them start out without a webserver.

For example: Creating a spring context directly within code:

```
ApplicationContext ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ("META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
SomeBean bean = ctx.getBean(...);
```

Comment: Thanks... But i need to start it through tomcat only.

Answer (score 0):

In a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) would appear to me to be the easiest way.  As a bonus, in recent versions of tomcat you can use this listener to register extra servlets that are initialised by Spring itself.